# Convert to Decimal Numbers

Tags: c++

I am supposed to be creating a program that converts roman numbers to its decimal values. I have done something, but the math is wrong. When entering MCMLXXVIII, I am supposed to get 1978, and instead I get 2178. I am using substrings to solve this problem, but I am not getting anywhere. Can somebody please advise me on what to do?

Thanks

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){


    int M = 1000;
    int D = 500;
    int C = 100;
    int L = 50;
    int X = 10;
    int V = 5;
    int I = 1;


    int num = 0;

    cout << " Enter the Roman Numeral Value: ";
    string roman;
    cin >> roman;

    string sub = roman.substr(0, 2);
    cout << sub << endl;





    for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++)
    {

        switch (roman.at(i))
        {

        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            num += M;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            num += D;
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            num += C;
            break;
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            num += L;
            break;
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
            num += X;
            break;
        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            num += V;
            break;
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            num += I;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: _`num += M;`_ Huh?? Really? Not something like `num += 1000;`  actually?

Comment: Im still a beginner, I am not really sure on what to do.

Comment: The code does exactly what you told it to. You do not convert roman numerals to decimal simply by adding them together. That's not how they work. Before you can write C++ code to implement it, you have to actually understand how Roman numerals work, which is something that has nothing to do with C++. Go ahead and invest some time in learning all about Roman numerals, then [ask your rubber duck for help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with writing your C++ code, if you need to.

Comment: I know how they work, I just don't know how to put it into the code to actually make it work.

Comment: Why are people down-voting? It might be code needing re-factoring, but it's a legitimate question

Comment: @AshwinNair - this isn't a programming question, its a logic question. And, it appears to be homework (though it might not be.) Either way, the poster hasn't really *described the problem* with the logic, but I would generally agree with you that this shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: @wahwahwah ...it's almost definitely a homework question (read comments to my answer below). A post is to be downvoted if it is unclear, shows no research attempted and is not useful. This post is clear. It has a tested code sample (copied I'm thinking) and I'm guessing it will be useful later. As for your points, I've encountered many questions on SO which are actually logic questions posed as programmatic ones which haven't been downvoted. The problem has been described as the code returning 2178 when 1978 is expected. I've currently upvoted to conteract downvotes.

Comment: There's even a tag for `logic`

Comment: @AshwinNair - Again, there was no attempt to describe or resolve the *the actual problem* and that's the reason for the downvoting. The fact that it's not really a programming question just amplifies the need to describe the problem. And, again, I don't think this question should have been downvoted - it would have been better to simply ask the poster to supply info on what they've tried.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're dealing with the string as sequential.

MCM is actually M + (M-C), that's 1000 + (1000-100) = 1000 + 900 = 1900.

Your code is simply adding it, which results in

MCM becoming M+C+M  which becomes 1000 + 100 + 1000 == 2100

That's why you're getting 2178 instead of 1978

What you need is a check to see if once you encounter a character, whether there are any characters ahead of it with a lower value.

So, if you encounter C, check if any of the chars ahead of it are M

If you encounter L, check if there's a C ahead of it,

If you encounter X, check if there's an L ahead of it and so on.

Here's an implementation that seems to work:

```
        int Main()
    {

        int num = 0;
        string ignoreNextChar = "false";

        string roman = "MCMLXXVIII".ToUpper();

        for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++)
        {
            if (ignoreNextChar == "true")
            {
                ignoreNextChar = "false";
                continue;
            }
            int anyBloodyNameHere = GetValue(roman.at(i));
            if ((i+1) < roman.length())
            {
                int nextVal = GetValue(roman.at(i + 1));
                if (nextVal > anyBloodyNameHere )
                {
                    num += nextVal - anyBloodyNameHere ;
                    ignoreNextChar = "true";
                    continue;
                }
            }
            num += GetValue(roman.at(i));
        }
        cout << num << endl;

    }

    int GetValue(char romanNumeral)
    {
        switch (romanNumeral)
        {

            case 'M':
                return 1000;
            case 'D':
                return 500;
            case 'C':
                return 100;
            case 'L':
                return 50;
            case 'X':
                return 10;
            case 'V':
                return 5;
            case 'I':
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I know how they work, I just don't know how to put it into the code to actually make it work.

Comment: I've added some code. Bear in mind this was csharp. So, it might need some tweaking.

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: VIII will show up as 8 with the above code. Even the case i considered, MCMLXXVIII, has an 8 in it

Comment: thanks for help, but the thing is I am not supposed to be using bool. Im supposed to be using functions, and substrings. Write a program that converts a Roman number such as MCMLXXVIII to its decimal number representation. Hint: First write a function that yields the numeric value of each of the letters. Then write a function that converts the Roman number string and returns its value as follows: Look at the first two characters of the string.

Comment: If the first has a larger value than the second, then simply convert the first, call the conversion function again for the substring starting with the second character, and add both values. If the first one has a smaller value than the second, compute the difference and add it to the conversion of the substring starting at the third character. Be sure that your conversion function returns the value 0 if the string is empty. You may also want to check that the Roman number string is non-empty before calling the conversion function from within the conversion function.

Comment: thats the question, but thank you for your help, I will use that when writing the program

Comment: im in a beginner class so I havent learned bool, or tempval yet

Comment: You can use a `string` instead of a `bool`. It's just a flag. You haven't learnt tempVal, but you've learnt roman and num? That's surprising. Also, you hadn't used `function`s in your own implementation. You can use `substring` everywhere you'd originally used `.at`. Might need to read up on it though.